# Printing the canvas in a new window

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I have a window say window1,there I have a canvas which I convert it to a image like so

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
var img = new Image();
img.src = can.toDataURL();
```

but I do a rotating of that Image in between like so

```
var img = new Image();
img.style.webkitTransformOrigin= "left bottom";
img.id = "printable";
img.style.webkitTransform = "translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg)";
img.src = can.toDataURL();
```

now I open it up in a new window

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=347.7200,height=755.9100");
myWindow.document.body.appendChild(img);
```

the problem is

1.The image is rotated after opening in a new window i.e., the images goes to the new window and then the css is applied then it rotates.
(I want it to rotate and then go to the new window,how can I do this?)

or

2.If I try to print it  the width and height of the image before rotating still exists.I want to print only the image not the whole body. 
See the scroll bar exist,ifI print this with the paper size of the image it gets shrinked due to the extra spaces on the body of the html.
[image]

Comment: try using `img.src = can.toDataURL();` before `img.style.webkitTransform = "translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg)";`

Comment: yes did it. But no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using CSS transforms the element size and position is still where it originally was defined as DOM sees it, [only the *rendering*](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/c431Le3n/) of it is affected by the transform.

So if an element is defined as for example 600x300 this will still be at the original position and the size it occupies, even if it is rendered at a different place, size, scale, rotation etc. This is why you see the scrollbars reflect the original size and orientation.

To work around this using canvas you can do an absolute rotation so that the image you extract represents the actual target size and orientation. This approach also eliminate the need to use correct prefix for each browser.

To do this define a new canvas with swapped width and height:

```
// note: assumes the width and height of source canvas is already set

var print = document.createElement("canvas");

// notice we swap height/width assuming 90° rotation
print.width = canvas.height;
print.height = canvas.width;
```

Now define transform on the context instead of the element:

```
var ctx = print.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(print.width>>1, print.height>>1);        // center origin
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);                                 // rotate 90°
ctx.drawImage(canvas, -canvas.width, -canvas.height);  // draw around origin
```

(or rotate about a corner if you prefer).

Extract image from here and insert into new page.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "110px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText("TEST", 10, 110);

var print = document.createElement("canvas");

// notice we swap height/width assuming 90° rotation
print.width = canvas.height;
print.height = canvas.width;

ctx = print.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(print.width>>1, print.height>>1);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
ctx.drawImage(canvas, -canvas.width>>1, -canvas.height>>1);

// extract as image, here shown in DOM
var img = new Image();
img.src = print.toDataURL();
img.onload = function() {
  // when this is called, we're ready to print.
};
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

```css
canvas {border:1px solid #555}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas><br>
```

You may also want to add this CSS to the new window:

```
body {margin:0;overflow:hidden}
```

Tip: there is no reason to set ID on the image element as you already have reference to it (`img`).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to render the canvas in new window. So I have modified your code to meet the requirement.

**Below code draws a simple line in new window:**

```
var img = new Image(), 
    can=document.createElement('canvas');

var ctx=can.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(300,150);
ctx.stroke();


img.style.webkitTransformOrigin= "left bottom";
img.id = "printable";
img.style.webkitTransform = "translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg)";
img.src = can.toDataURL();
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=347.7200,height=755.9100");
myWindow.document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/7xaokpzz/3/

Note: Please allow popup :)

Hope this helps!

Regards,

Ashok

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to transform the canvas' context before drawing the image on it like so:

```
var imgURL = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports",
    img = new Image();

img.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 canvas.width = e.target.height;
 canvas.height = e.target.width;

 context.translate(e.target.width,0);
 context.rotate(Math.PI/2);
 context.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);

 document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});

img.src = imgURL;
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v21a09vu/)